# Discord.py-Rewrite Sending an Error message when there is an unknown command or other error

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to be able to send a message like `await ctx.send("Error: Unknown command. Do -help for acceptable commands."` or something like that (FYI, I'm not asking how to remove the `Help is already a defined function` or something like that.); But I don't know how to make an error message for something that isn't a command, Like if there is an error with a command like they didn't put any parameters then I'm able to make an error for that `@command.error` then i define it. But I'm not sure how to start this. And if possible, would there be a way where at the bottom of the code, is checked what the error is? like if they need admin but they are missing it then `if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):` or if they need to allow server members to message them, maybe it would have a different thing to check?

TLDR; I want to be able to have at the bottom of my code a thing that checks if there was an error and if so, if its caused by the command not existing (then it says something with `ctx.send`) but if its caused by missing admin or missing role, or possibly them needing to allow server members to dm them in privacy settings, then it also says something. I don't want to have to define an error for every command.

### Extra

I also have a command that requires numbers to work, and i want a block of code that checks if its an integer, and if not, gives an error saying that it needs to be a number. Then checks if its a positive number, and if not, gives an error.

Comment: Refer this [example](https://gist.github.com/EvieePy/7822af90858ef65012ea500bcecf1612) on basic error handlng.

Answer (score 1):

Discord.py has a [`on_command_error`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=on_command_error#discord.on_command_error) event, which takes the error as argument. You can use it this way:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    await ctx.send(f"An error occured: {str(error)}")
```

Here's a list of every [discord exeptions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands%20errors#exceptions).
If you want a custom message for each error, you can do it this way:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound):
        await ctx.send("Unknown command")
```