# Getting the command information

Tags: discord.py

Is there any way, I can get what command is being used at the time of the following event:

```
@bot.event
async def on_command(command):
    print(command)
```

I need it for statistics purpose, I have searched the library but failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation says, [`on_command`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=on_command#discord.on_command) events have a [`ctx`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context#discord.ext.commands.Context) argument. Every `Context` object have a `command` attribute, which is a [`commands.Command`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search.html?q=commands.command) object:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_command(ctx):
    print(ctx.command)
```

However, if you want to count only commands that were successfuly invoked, you can use the [`on_command_completion`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=on_command#discord.on_command_completion) event:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_command_completion(ctx):
    print(ctx.command)
```

Combined with [`on_command_error`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=on_command#discord.on_command_error), you'll be able to know what command users find hard to invoke:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    print(ctx.command.name)
    print(error)
```

Here's a small answer that I wrote recently about [error management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62771154/discord-py-rewrite-sending-an-error-message-when-there-is-an-unknown-command-or/62774467#62774467). It would allow you to create a log system.

Answer (score 2):

Yes on_command(context) takes the context argument. And the context has a `.command` attribute which gives you the command name.

In code it would look like this:

```
@bot.event
async def on_command(context):
    print(context.command)
```

You can read more about everything the context argument contains here: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?#discord.ext.commands.Context

Comment: Aww thanks, dear, I was lost. command.command worked ;)