# Print error code doesn't work (PyCharm, Python 3.8)

Tags: discord.py, python-3.8, args, keyword-argument

I found this code in Stackoverflow which prints any error messages. But it doesn't print the error. Just to say if it is relevant, PyCharm said that Bot doesn't have attribute AppInfo.

Code:

````
@bot.event
async def on_error(event, *args, **kwargs):
    embed = discord.Embed(title=':x: Event Error', colour=0xe74c3c)
    embed.add_field(name='Event', value=event)
    embed.description = '```py\n%s\n```' % traceback.format_exc()
    embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    await bot.AppInfo.owner.send(embed=embed)
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another Stackoverflow question ([Discord.py-Rewrite Sending an Error message when there is an unknown command or other error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62771154/discord-py-rewrite-sending-an-error-message-when-there-is-an-unknown-command-or)) which has the answer. As it seems, there was no need to complicate the command as the case with my code.

Answer (score 0):

The `bot` class does not have an `AppInfo` attribute by default. To create it, include on your `on_ready()` event that attribute:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    if not hasattr(bot, 'AppInfo'):
        bot.AppInfo = await bot.application_info()
```

Doing this, it will be available when it is used in your `on_error` event.

Comment: But it still doesn't print the send the error. I tried doing a simple error where the command is not in the code but the bot doesn't send the message.

Comment: How are you actually trying to trigger an error?

Comment: <prefix> <something-which-isn't-command> which then brings up the error: <something-which-isn't-command> is not found

Comment: Try awaiting the `await bot.application_info()` within your `on_error` event.